# Saving Vuex State on mounted lifecycle

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to save the application's root state on `mounted` lifecycle of VueJS and freeze the copy in `$root`'s `data`, and my attempt is as following,

```
  mounted() {
    this.globalState = this.$store.state;
  },
  data () {
    return {
      globalState: null
    }
  }
```

However this approach is updating `globalState` so I came up with another way to freeze it by using `Object.freeze()` but with no luck it keeps updating.

Also I've tried to copy the `this.$store.state` to a `const` variable and update `globalState` via it, but it also fails.

My last attempt is as following, I know it's an ugly code but please bear with it.

```
    let emptyObj = {};
    Object.defineProperty(emptyObj, 'globalState',{
        value: this.$store.state,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false
      }
    );
    this.globalState = emptyObj.globalState;
```

My question is, how can I copy and freeze the initial state of the application and store it in single `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want reactivity on the copy of the state object its better to create a custom option in your components option instead of freezing the object in the `data` option.

```
import {cloneDeep} from "lodash"

export default{
    myGlobalState: null,
    mounted() {
        this.$options.myGlobalState = cloneDeep(this.$store.state);
    }
}
```

Your custom option can be accesed using [`vm.$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) and is not reactive

```
this.$options.myGlobalState
```

Comment: Thanks your answer worked.

EDIT: It stopped being reactive in `data` object too, I've tested.

Comment: @KaungMyatLwin vuejs sets up getter/setters for the properties in `data` option to make them reactive. If you do not want reactivity you can save some overhead by creating custom option

Comment: Yep I'm very aware of that. Didn't know I have to recursively clone the state to make it immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using a computed value which has an empty setter.

e.g.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

{
  data() { return {} },
  computed: {
    globalState: {
      get() {
        return _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state);
      },
      set(input) {}
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.globalState = {test2:456};
    // this won't change anything
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/bvgMRR?editors=1111

Comment: Still doesn't work. If there's mutations to the `store`, it still updates `globalState`.

Comment: then you need to clone deep. I use lodash but there are other options

Comment: actually, @Vamsi Krishna's answer is better. but i'll just keep mine here anyway =]

Comment: Of course, yours is an alt way for someone who isn't in my use case.